# Git diff different directories across branches

Tags: git, git-branch, git-diff

I'd like to compare two branches that have diverged significantly. I would also like to limit my comparison to a particular subdirectory where the files were moved in only one of the branches.

Example layout:

```
branch-a
└── sub
    ├── file1
    ├── file2
    └── file3
branch-b
├── file2
├── file3
└── file4
```

Running `git diff -M branch-b` from branch-a correctly diffs the files, but it includes all changes, not just those in *sub*. I've tried using `--relative`, but that seems to prevent move detection.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I figured it out:

`git diff branch-a:sub branch-b`